# How to put HTML in jQuery .text()

Tags: jquery, html

I couldn't find this anywhere, partly because its keywords are pretty common.

```
$('.pause_button').text('<img src="../imgs/icons/control_pause_blue.png" alt="Resume" /> Resume');
```

How can this be printed as HTML and not convert the brackets and apostrophes?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make use of the `.html` function avaialble in jQuery, [**`.html()`**](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

For example:

```
$('div.demo-container').html('<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>');
```

In your case

```
$('.pause_button').html('<img src="../imgs/icons/control_pause_blue.png" 
alt="Resume" /> Resume');
```

Answer (score 8):

`.text()` actually escapes all HTML specific characters, `.html()` doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$('.pause_button').html('<img src="../imgs/icons/control_pause_blue.png" alt="Resume" /> Resume');
```

Answer (score 6):

use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$('.pause_button').html('<img src="../imgs/icons/control_pause_blue.png" alt="Resume" /> Resume');
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `.html();`.